# Signing blockchain transaction using a key stored in Google Cloud KMS

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I have a requirement **to secure the private key which is used for signing a blockchain transaction**. While we are evaluating option of using HSM (Hardware Security Module), I was equally wondering about the applicability of Google Cloud KMS. Your help will be highly appreciated if you can answer my following queries :)

1. Can we save a key in Google Cloud KMS which may have been generated outside?
2. Assume that I have already saved my private key in Google Cloud KMS, which one of the following is true/possible?

   - Using an API call, the key stored in KMS is retrieved first and then it can be used to sign the blockchain transaction. But in this case, security can be compromised once the key is outside the KMS.
   - The key never leaves Google Cloud KMS once stored. Instead, a blockchain transaction can be sent to Google Cloud KMS for signing the transaction using the key managed by it. Here I assume that KMS may provide me some customization features so that I can execute the signing process or KMS may have capability to execute a piece of code.
   - Google Cloud KMS can't execute specialized tasks (like signing a Blockchain transaction), it just does the encryption/decryption only.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud KMS doesn't store keys for retrieval; instead, it stores keys and keeps them secret. I believe your third bullet is closest to the situation.

In your situation, I would suggest wrapping the blockchain private key with a KMS key and then storing the wrapped private key somewhere. To sign a transaction, the app would use KMS to unwrap the key then sign it in software locally.

Yes, this exposes the calling app to the private key and makes you responsible for that security.

A question: what algorithm would you like signing support for? Google NEXT is next week, look for some announcements from us that you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your quick response. :) I will get back to you asap on your query...

Comment: At NEXT we announced support for Google-managed HSMs as a part of cloud KMS, including support for asymmetric encryption and signing algorithms, please see https://cloud.google.com/hsm/